# LLVM Missing Terminator

Tags: c, llvm, llvm-ir

LLVM is telling me that a basic block is missing a terminator:

```
Basic Block in function 'main' does not have terminator!
label %bb2
```

However, I'm inserting a branch and I'm even checking where it's being inserted:

```
LLVMPositionBuilderAtEnd(builder, t);
printf("inserting br at %s\n",
    LLVMGetBasicBlockName(LLVMGetInsertBlock(builder))); 
LLVMBuildBr(builder, merge_bb);
```

However, in my output, the basic block which is missing the terminator is one of the blocks printed:

```
inserting br at bb2
inserting br at bb4
```

I tried reading the bitcode generated with `llvm-dis` but it gives me another error:

```
llvm-dis: error: Invalid record (Producer: 'LLVM10.0.0' Reader: 'LLVM 10.0.0')
```

But this error only appears when the terminator error also occurs so I'm not sure if they're related.

Comment: You can call dump() on blocks (and almost everything else in LLVM) to dump them to stderr. Try that.